# How to tell new employer that I am on holiday if I am supposed to be working in my current company?

Tags: new-job, notice-period, start-date

The situation I ended up is a bit weird.

Let's put the facts down:

- I am working in company A for few years.
- I got a contract to start working in compaby B by 1st of month X. Already signed.
- Company B wanted me to start as soon as possible. By the date they confirmed they wanted to hire me, I told them the earliest I can start is 1st of month X. That is why we put that date in the contract.
- Although I was not very explicit, i.e. never written, just in oral conversation, it was clear that I can only start on 1st of month X because I have to work in company A till 31st of month X-1 and need time to relocate (it is another city).
- I expected actually to leave company B by 31st of month X-2. Therefore having holiday the full month X-1.
- It turned out they allow me to quit earlier, so I can have holiday two months! Great so I can be off on month X-1 and X-2.

So far so good... but:

- I want to be travelling to other countries during month X-1 and X-2. During the two months is ok if I come back to the country of the company few times. But need to be pre-planned so I know how to organize my trip, flight tickets etc.
- Company B assumes I am working in the country so they want me to drop by a couple of times for some required paperwork.
- Company B wants to fly me out of the country at end of month X-2 for one week. That is for the paperwork.

So, how can I...

a) Be able to schedule my drops by their office when it is convenient for my travel schedule? I.e. how to tell them "I cannot come to sign on the day you proposed, I can only on next Tuesday at 3 pm" If I am supposed to be around, I am supposed to have more flexibility.

b) Be able to match the flight they want to buy my with my trip plans?

it comes to the question: Should I tell I have a trip plan during that period and then ask them to please help to adapt to it or should I not reveal that, and just try to fit the appointments as good as possible with my trips?

Comment: Have you considered that company B may entertain the possibility of allowing you to take a vacation at some time during x-1 and x-2 if you tell them you can start sooner? a 2-4 week vacation is much preferred to immediately coming across as a liar.

Comment: I mean, they wanted me to start as early as possible. Yes the liar thing is the worsr, that is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you not just take some vacation after you start? Most companies I have worked for will let you take some pre-planned vacation if you discuss it prior to your start date, or shortly after you start

Comment: @Link0352 maybe could if had planned before hand like that. Vut actually no because they wanted me to start as soon as possible. So now difficult to ask them that. Plus we already signed the contract and everything to start on month X so it is weird if ask them to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is simply to be honest. It's perfectly normal for a company not to require you to work your full notice period, and you shouldn't need to explain your availability to your new employer. Note also that being allowed to leave before the end of your notice period doesn't necessarily allow you to start with the new employer - some employers like to have a period of "garden leave" to make sure that your duties have been properly handed over while you're still available to call for help if necessary.

If you need to try and organise dates where you're around for visiting the new office, just be honest about it.

> Hi *New Boss*, I wanted to confirm my availability for the proposed start date of *date*. I am also available for the trip to *location* on *date* to complete the paperwork. Are there any other dates when you'll need me to visit the office before my start date? If so, I can add them to my diary now to ensure that I can fit them around my relocation and other travel plans during my hiatus.

Comment: So far this seems kind of my favourite answer. Try yo arrange the meetings and trips without telling them explicitely my plans but not lying either.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like the problem is you want to travel but don't want your new company to know you're travelling, because then they might want you to work earlier.

I would be upfront, telling them, "I thought the earliest month I could leave my company X, but since we talked it turns out I can leave in month X-2. Ideally, I'd like to have those two months to travel, but if you really need me earlier I can start earlier." Maybe you argue a little time off now would make you more productive later.

They could easily say, "no, we need you now" and ruin your travel plans, which is unfortunate. But I wouldn't try to deal with all the complications of deceiving them, and you don't want to risk starting the relationship off on the wrong foot.

Comment: No, I mean, they would not exige me to start earlier and ruin the whole travelling. But if they know it, it affects trust and reputation. I made them believe I cannot start earlier because I need to work in company A and need to arrange my moving. But then they found out I have a full plan to travel around.

Comment: @Worker Oh, I see. So company A never required the two months' notice. Sorry to say it, but trying to deceive them in the first place is what risks your trust and reputation. I think you need to either tell them you can start earlier, or not risk travelling around.

Comment: "But if they know it, it affects trust and reputation" So basically what you're asking us is to help you lie to your new employer in a way that they don't know you're lying?

Comment: No. What I want is to find the best solution, either telling truth or not telling the truth explicitely. But, in any of the cases not lying explicitely.

Answer (score 6):

Let me put this to you plainly. If I hired you and wanted you to start as soon as possible and you said you had to give notice and this was the first available date. That is fine if I agreed to it. If I find out later you actually took a holiday instead of working the notice you told me of, the offer would instantly be withdrawn because you are lying to me. If however, you go to me and say, I am available earlier than expected. I would rejoice and start you earlier. In no case is taking a vacation appropriate in this circumstance.

Comment: Recharging the batteries between two jobs can also be beneficial for the new job. Unless the company attitude is "squeeze the lemon then throw it away".

Comment: @L.Dutch Agreed, but lying about it is not good and could cost OP their job.

Comment: We don't know about if 'lying' is involved. You as a future employer can assume what you want, it's actually not your business. I think you reaction is typical of why the OP needs to be careful with what they disclose and how.

Comment: They agreed 'the first available date' is date x though, and put this date in the contract. It doesn't matter if he has to work or decides to go on a vacation. It's OPs first available date.

Comment: WE do know lying is involved, he told them his first available date was due to the notice he had to give.

Comment: You can give notice and then use up the rest of your accrued holidays for one month. Being on holiday during month X-1 does not change the fact that the contract ends on the 31st of month X-1.

Comment: The OP told them he couldn't start due to a contractual obligation, he lied if he intended to take vacation. And most places (at least in the US) don't allow vacation during the notice period.